# Why does uninstalling boost uninstall aptitude and libreoffice?

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall

When I do `sudo apt-get remove 'libboost*'` in Ubuntu 14.04
I get the following response:

```
      The following packages will be REMOVED:
      aptitude libboost-atomic1.54.0 libboost-chrono1.54.0 libboost-context1.54.0
      libboost-date-time1.54.0 libboost-filesystem1.54.0
      libboost-graph-parallel1.54.0 libboost-graph1.54.0 libboost-iostreams1.54.0
      libboost-locale1.54.0 libboost-log1.54.0 libboost-math1.54.0
      libboost-mpi-python1.54.0 libboost-mpi1.54.0 libboost-program-options1.54.0
      libboost-python1.54.0 libboost-random1.54.0 libboost-regex1.54.0
      libboost-serialization1.54.0 libboost-signals1.54.0 libboost-system1.54.0
      libboost-system1.55.0 libboost-test1.54.0 libboost-thread1.54.0
      libboost-thread1.55.0 libboost-timer1.54.0 libboost-wave1.54.0 libcmis-0.4-4
      libconsole-bridge0.2 libdbus-cpp2 libfcl0 libmirclient7
      libmirclientplatform-mesa libogre-1.9.0 liborcus-0.6-0 libprocess-cpp1
      libqpidcommon2 libreoffice libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer
      libreoffice-base libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-base-drivers
      libreoffice-calc libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome
      libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-ogltrans
      libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-presentation-minimizer
      libreoffice-report-builder-bin libreoffice-sdbc-firebird
      libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb libreoffice-writer libsslcommon2 libsslcommon2-dev
      libtorrent-rasterbar8 libubuntu-location-service0 libunity-scopes1
      liburdfdom-model-state0.2 liburdfdom-model0.2 liburdfdom-sensor0.2
      liburdfdom-world0.2 python3-uno qbittorrent unity-plugin-scopes
      unity-scope-mediascanner2 unity-scope-scopes unoconv
```

Why does it want to remove such programms as `aptitude` and `libreoffice` and how do I prevent that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because these packages have a dependency on one of the `libboost*` packages you are removing.

For example, `libreoffice-core` depends on `libboost-system1.54.0`

So if you remove `libboost-system1.54.0`, `libreoffice-core` will not work.  Nor will all of the `libreoffice` packages that depend on `libreoffice-core`.  So the package manager wants to remove them instead of leaving you with a bunch of broken packages.

You could theoretically prevent this, but why? You would be left with a bunch of broken packages on your system.

Probably the question you should ask is why you need to remove `libboost*` That appears to be a really bad idea.

Comment: Then what is the right way to install the newest version of libboost? Will libreoffice not work if I install libboost1.58?

Comment: That may be the question that you initially wanted to ask, but it's really a different question, so I suggest asking that separately.

Comment: It's too late, I already uninstalled it.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that.  I hope you can recover from this without reinstalling your whole system.

Comment: Why is that a bad idea? It wasn't installed by default.

Comment: If there were no undesirable effects to the actions you took, you would not be here asking about it.